# How to delay after on("mouseenter") 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, onmouseover

Here is my code.

In the 4th line, I want to run this.openList after 2 seconds when mouse entered lastItemsLink.

How can I do that?

```
lastItemsLink = $(".last-items"),
openLastItemsList = {
    init: function() {
        lastItemsLink.on("mouseenter", this.openList);
        lastItemsLink.on("mouseleave", this.closeList);
    },
    openList: function() {
        lastItemsContainer.stop(false, true).slideDown("fast");
    },
    closeList: function() {
        lastItemsContainer.stop(false, true).fadeOut("fast");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to do something like

```
lastItemsLink = $(".last-items"),
openLastItemsList = {
    init: function () {
        lastItemsLink.on("mouseenter", this.openList);
        lastItemsLink.on("mouseleave", this.closeList);
    },
    openList: function () {
        openLastItemsList.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            lastItemsContainer.stop(false, true).slideDown("fast");
            delete openLastItemsList.timer;
        }, 2000)
    },
    closeList: function () {
        if (openLastItemsList.timer) {
            clearTimeout(openLastItemsList.timer)
        } else {
            lastItemsContainer.stop(false, true).fadeOut("fast");
        }
    }
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v4N4F/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout):

```
lastItemsLink.on("mouseenter", function () {
    setTimeout(this.openList, 2000)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try .delay() function
[click here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
this.delay(2000).openList
```

might work give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
$('#a').mouseenter(e => {
    if (timeout != null) { clearTimeout(timeout); }
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('mouseenter after delay');
    }, 500);
})
.mouseleave(e => { if (timeout != null) { clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null; } });
var timeout;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">[Hover at me]</div>
```